Woman does everything to get a marriage proposal
The actress wants to get married but the guy doesn't. She ends up talking him into moving in with him, then changes the theme of his house, puts in a baby room, and leaves wedding magazines on the coffee table. She then gives him an ultimatum to marry her or propose by a certain date. When the guy does not meet her demand, she destroys his life...
He ends up tricking her at the end by letting her think they are really getting married in Vegas, with the help of his friends, but in the end they do not get married and I believe she gets arrested. 

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

Though I admit more basic details are usually needed, you pretty much described the entire plot, so the answer's below. :)

You're looking for Love Stinks from 1999 with French Stewart and Bridgette Wilson.

Seth Winnick has it all: a successful career in television, good friends, and a passionate relationship with beautiful Chelsea. However, when he fails to make a timely marriage proposal, Chelsea tries to make his life hell.

It ends like you said: He fakes a wedding in Vegas and she gets arrested. Here's the trailer:



